# iOS 6 - MPMoviePlayerViewController generates CGContext errors and is stuck on 'Loading...'

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, loading, cgcontext

Was working fine earlier, but for some reason I am getting all these issues.
The URL is correct and is for an MP4 file.

Code:

```
[movieView.moviePlayer setContentURL:videoLink];
[movieView.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[self presentViewController:movieView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Log:

```
   <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
   <Error>: CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0
   <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
   <Error>: CGContextDrawShading: invalid context 0x0
   <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
```

**EDIT**

Looks like the CGContext errors are a bug in the framework, so not much to do about those. But still don't understand the 'Loading..' error. I have verified the URLs and they all play the videos fine on web browsers. And logging the URL of the movieplayer shows the correct one. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue with playback was low connectivity that wasn't being detected by my reachability methods.